# 2-d array of doubles failed to initialize

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I am making several calls to a function that initializes 2-d arrays of doubles.  The first three calls are successful, but the fourth call fails.  Code is:

```
double **scmass;
double **scdv;
double **dvmatches;
double **zpp;
```

...

```
scmass = init_d2darr(numrow,numcol);
scdv = init_d2darr(numrow,numcol);
dvmatches = init_d2darr(numrow,numcol);
zpp = init_d2darr(numrow,numcol);
```

...

```
double ** init_d2darr(int isize, int jsize) {
int m,n;
printf("in array initialize 1\n");
printf("isize: %i\njsize: %i\n",isize,jsize);
/* how many rows */
double **arr = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * isize);
printf("after row initialization\n");
if (arr == NULL) {
    printf("malloc failed for arr in init_d2darr.\n");
    return NULL;
}
else {
    /* now how many cols */
    for (m=0; m<=isize; m++) {
        arr[m] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * jsize);
        if (arr[m] == NULL) {
            printf("malloc failed for arr[%d] in init_d2darr.\n",m);
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            /* initialize all to zero */
            for (n=0; n<jsize; n++) {
                arr[m][n] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("in array initialize 2\n");
return arr;
```

Output looks like:

```
in array initialize 1
isize: 20
jsize: 21
after row initialization
in array initialize 2
in array initialize 1
isize: 20
jsize: 21
after row initialization
in array initialize 2
in array initialize 1
isize: 20
jsize: 21
```

The program actually runs all the way through when in debug mode, however, when I make a release executable and attempt to run it, the program crashes and I get the error "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."  I'm on windows vista with Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.  Could anyone give me any advice?  Thanks!

Jade

Edit: the declaration of the function (in a header file) is

```
double ** init_d2darr(int isize, int jsize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer for-loop:

```
for (m=0; m <= isize; m++)
```

this should be:

```
for (m=0; m < isize; m++)
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but why would that make it crash on the fourth call (or any call)?  Wouldn't that just give me an extra place in the array?

Comment: Oh wait, I see.  I size the first dimension to isize, but then I'm trying to access and initialize the isize+1 position, which I'm assuming for my hard drive that position happens to be occupied, and doesn't want to be overwritten.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class double_array {
    double* arr;
    int arrsize;
public:
    double_array(int newsize) {
        arr = new double[newsize];
        arrsize = newsize;
        for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
            arr[i] = 0;
    }
    double_array(const double_array& other) {
        arr = new double[arrsize = other.arrsize];
        for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
            arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }
    double& operator[](int index) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        if (index >= arrsize)
            throw std::runtime_error("Attempted to access array out of bounds!");
#endif
        return arr[index];
    }
    const double& operator[](int index) const {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        if (index >= arrsize)
            throw std::runtime_error("Attempted to access array out of bounds!");
#endif
        return arr[index];
    }
    int size() {
        return arrsize;
    }
    ~double_array() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
};
std::vector<double_array> scmass(numrows, numcols);
std::vector<double_array> scdv(numrows, numcols);
std::vector<double_array> dvmatches(numrows, numcols);
std::vector<double_array> zpp(numrows, numcols);
```

Easy.